# When you have multiple reaches, are you free to use any of them?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, combat, opportunity-attack, reach

This question is prompted by the Eldritch Claw Tattoo which can allow your attacks to "reach a target up to 15 feet away from you..." and specifically relates to Attacks of Opportunity.

> You can make an opportunity Attack when a Hostile creature that you can see moves out of your reach.

In a situation where I have a Glaive, and have activated the Eldritch Claw Tattoo, do I have 3 different reaches?

- Unarmed Strike (5 feet)
- Glaive (10 feet)
- Glaive & Unarmed Strike (15 feet, thanks to the Eldritch Claw Tattoo)

Or, does the Eldritch Claw Tattoo's effect make all of those attacks' reach *only* 15 feet?

Is this accurate, and can I make an Attack of Opportunity with any of them, where someone leaves that specific attack's reach?

Comment: I have seen that you are starting to become an active editor. I think that is great. So I thought it would be good if you read https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9112/44723 to get a better understanding of how people engage with editing :)